# Weak convergence of measures

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that a sequence $(\mu_{k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converges weakly to some measure $\mu$, where $(X,d)$ is a polish space and the measures are Borel probability measures.

If for some Borel set $A$ we have $\mu_{k}(A)=c$ (where c is a constant) for all $k$, do we know anything about $\mu(A)$? I know $\mu_{k}(A)\to \mu(A)$ if $\mu(\partial A)=0$, but I would be interested to know if there's anything we can do in this case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A$ is open then $\mu(A) \le c$ while if $A$ is closed then $\mu(A) \ge c$.  But for general Borel $A$, $\mu(A)$ could be anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: $A=(0,2)$ and $\mu_n=\delta_{1/n}$ gives $\mu=\delta_0$ hence $\mu_n(A)=1$ for every $n\geqslant1$ but $\mu(A)=0$, while $A=[0,1)$ and $\mu_n=\delta_{-1/n}$ gives $\mu=\delta_0$ hence $\mu_n(A)=0$ for every $n\geqslant1$ but $\mu(A)=1$.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the fast reply.